# How to define a template specialization for a templated function for a templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have a class, something like `BizClass` below. I'd like to define a templated function and a specialization for a particular concrete type. I'm not sure of the appropriate syntax.

```
template <class Foo> 
class BizClass {
 public:
  template <typename Bar>
  void Action(Container<Bar> m);
  // Foo is used somewhere else...
};

// This seems to work.
template <class Foo>
template <typename Bar>
inline void BizClass<Foo>::Action(Container<Bar> m) {}

// This specialization doesn't compile, where Foobar is a concrete class.
template <class Foo>
inline void BizClass<Foo>::Action(Container<FooBar> m) {}
```

How do I handle the template specialization for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code sample titled `This seems to work.`, that is just defining the body for the template function, it is not a specialization.

In the second sample you attempt to specialize a template which is a member of another unspecialized template. This is not allowed.

You need to also specialize `BizClass` if you want to specialize `Action`, e.g. here is an example with `Foo=int` and `Bar=char`:

```
template<> template<>
inline void BizClass<int>::Action(Container<char> m)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I handle the template specialization for this case?

As far I know, the C++ forbids specialization of a method, inside a template struct/class, without specializing the struct/class itself.

But you can use overloading: make `Action (Container<FooBar> m)` a not-template method

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename>
struct Container
 { };

struct FooBar
 { };

template <typename Foo> 
struct BizClass
 {
   template <typename Bar>
   void Action (Container<Bar> m);

   void Action (Container<FooBar> m);
 };

template <typename Foo>
template <typename Bar>
inline void BizClass<Foo>::Action (Container<Bar> m)
 { std::cout << "Action() generic version" << std::endl; }

template <typename Foo>
inline void BizClass<Foo>::Action (Container<FooBar> m)
 { std::cout << "Action() FooBar version" << std::endl; }

int main ()
 {
   BizClass<int>  bci;

   bci.Action(Container<int>{});     // print Action() generic version
   bci.Action(Container<FooBar>{});  // print Action() FooBar version
 }
```

Comment: It is fine to specialize just a member function of a class template